# The set $H=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\;3x+2y=5 \},$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Kindly check if my proof is correct. Thanks for your time and efforts.

**MY PROOF**

For all $n\in \Bbb{N},$ let $(x_n,y_n)\in H$ such that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y),$ as $n\to \infty.$ We show that $(x,y)\in H.$

However, $(x_n,y_n)\in H$ implies $3x_n+2y_n=5,$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}.$ As $n\to \infty, $

$$ 3x+2y=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(3x_n+2y_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}5=5 .     $$
Hence, $(x,y)\in H$ which implies that the set, $H=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\;3x+2y=5 \},$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb{R^2}$

Comment: Looks good. Maybe cite the algebra of limits theorem?

Comment: I mean, sure I guess. But since it's a straight line you could just say that.

Comment: Nice proof.....

Comment: This seems a bit odd, you start assuming that $3x_n + 2y_n = 5$ for all $n$ and that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$, of course $3 x + 2y = 5$ follows from that. But I don't think you proved anything, because you assumed everything

Comment: @Ben W: Nice trick!

Comment: @caverac: Assumed everything?

Comment: In the sense that you assumed that no matter where you start, you always end up on the line. So of course, it is not a surprise that every point you choose ends on the line (because you assumed so)

Comment: @caverac: Hmm... That's what makes the proof easy though! You can also share yours with me! I'd be glad!

Comment: Equivalent statement is: the sets $H_{+}=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\;3x+2y>5 \}$ and
$H_{-}=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\;3x+2y<5 \}$ are open subsets of $ \Bbb{R^2}$.

Comment: @Aleksas Domarkas: Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: The statement $\lim(3x_n + 2x_n = 5)$ does not make sense and is meaningless.  What I believe you mean is:  $3x + 2x = \lim (3x_n + 2x_n) = \lim 5 = 5$.  But you should state explicitly that $\lim (3x_n + 2x_n) = 3\lim x_n + 2\lim x_n$

Comment: @fleablood: That's good! I'll adjust!

Comment: @fleablood: Corrected! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks Good! Alternatively, take $\alpha=(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus H$. Take $r=d(\alpha,H)>0$, the distance from the point $\alpha$ to the line $H$.  Then $$B(\alpha,r) \subset \Bbb R^2 \setminus H$$ showing $\Bbb R^2 \setminus H$ is open.

Comment: I love this one!  (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm overcomplicating this, but here's where I think your proof fails

Imagine that $H = \{(x, y)\in \Bbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$. And now I am going to apply *your* same argument

> For all $n\in \Bbb{N},$ let $(x_n,y_n)\in H$ such that $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y),$ as $n\to \infty.$ We show that $(x,y)\in H.$
>
> However, $(x_n,y_n)\in H$ implies $x_n^2+y_n^2<1,$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}.$ As $n\to \infty, $
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n^2 + y_n^2 = x^2 + y^2 < 1$$
> Hence, $(x,y)\in H$ which implies that the set, $H=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}:\;x^2+y^2<1 \},$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$

Do you see the problem?

Comment: Hmm... You are right because, $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ which will imply that $(x,y)\notin H.$ However, it's all about the approach used. In that scenerio, I believe mine is correct, right?

Comment: This has the same general *form* as the OP's proof, but the error stems from something not present there.  The OP is tacitly using the theorem that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(u_n+v_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n+\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n$ (provided the limits on the right hand side both exist), while the "proof" here tacitly uses the **incorrect** (non-)theorem that $u_n\lt c\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\lt c$. The *correct* theorem is $u_n\lt c\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n\le c$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh yeah! That's the missing part here $u_n < c \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \color{red}{\leq} c$. I'm going to delete this, don't want to contribute to the clutter. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @caverac, you're welcome for the clarification. The flaw is somewhat subtle (it took me, at least, a bit of thought to see what was wrong in it) and possibly worth preserving on that basis.

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your proof to make one tacit step explicit in the display: If $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$, then

$$3x+2y=3\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+2\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(3x_n+2y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}5=5$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a typo! (+1)

Comment: If your comment here was intended for dmtri, you can delete it (here) by hovering your cursor to the right of the timestamp until an X appears.

Comment: It was meant for you as well. As you know, I made typos and you did well to make corrections. Thanks, once again!

Comment: OK. But I didn't even notice the typo!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have $3x+2y$ in the 3 line from the bottom....

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a typo! (+1)